# django User permissions and Permission Required Mixin

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

In this code, Django will check for all the permission in the tuple  **permission_required** and if the user having all the permission get access to the view. I want to provide the view if the user having any permission in the given list or tuple. Eg: In this particular case if the user only having the **polls.can_open** permission I want to provide the view

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View)
    permission_required = ('polls.can_open', 'polls.can_edit')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/blob/master/braces/views/_access.py) in [django-braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces) is what you need.

the doc is [here](https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access.html#multiplepermissionsrequiredmixin). Demo:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from braces import views


class SomeProtectedView(views.LoginRequiredMixin,
                        views.MultiplePermissionsRequiredMixin,
                        TemplateView):

    #required
    permissions = {
        "all": ("blog.add_post", "blog.change_post"),
        "any": ("blog.delete_post", "user.change_user")
    }
```

> This view mixin can handle multiple permissions by setting the mandatory permissions attribute as a dict with the keys any and/or all to a list or tuple of permissions. The all key requires the request.user to have all of the specified permissions. The any key requires the request.user to have at least one of the specified permissions.

Comment: It is not raising Permission denied when the the permission is not met. Instead it redirects to the login page. Is there any way to raise permission denied when the person is logged in ?

Comment: and ofcourse adding redirect_unauthenticated_users=True since we have to redirect if not logged in.

Answer (score 5):

The mixin doesn't support OR conditions by default, but you can simply override the [`has_permission()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin.has_permission) method to do the permission checks yourself. Something like:

```
def has_permission(self):
    user = self.request.user
    return user.has_perm('polls.can_open') or user.has_perm('polls.can_edit')
```

Comment: shouldn't the last line be something like 'return any(user.has_perm(p) for p in self.permission_required)' so you can be more general and could be an OrPermissionsRequiredMixin !